# Is there a word or phrase for a time period in which you find yourself unable to make any progress?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am sure this has happened to most people. For example, you start learning playing tennis, and for the first few month you progress steadily. However, after a certain period of time, you are in a phase where it is hard to improve anymore. Not that there is no room for improvement, but you simply can't for no reason. Then maybe after another few month, you start to improve again. I want to know whether there is a word or phrase that describes the second phase where you find yourself unable to improve for no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps *plateau*:

> [plateau](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/plateau)
>   noun
>   2 a period or state of little or no growth or decline:
>   *to reach a plateau in one's career.*
>
> verb (used without object), pla·teaued, pla·teau·ing.
>   to reach a state or level of little or no growth or decline, especially to stop increasing or progressing; remain at a stable level of achievement; level off:
>   *After a period of uninterrupted growth, sales began to plateau.*
>
> (Dictionary.com)

Example:

> I’ve been playing tennis for a few months, and I’ve been making a lot of progress.
>
> - But now I feel I’ve reach a plateau.
> - But now I feel I’ve plateaued.